# Do PC emulators emulate CPU bugs?

Tags: cpu, emulation, hardware, cpu-architecture

Some CPUs have bugs at the architecture level (such as [these](http://wiki.osdev.org/CPU_Bugs)), and it's possible that some programs developed for these CPUs also have bugs which are compensated by the CPU's own ones. If so, such program wouldn't work on a 'perfect' emulator. Do PC emulators include these bugs? For example, Bochs is known to be pretty accurate, does it handle them 'properly', as a real CPU would?

P.S. Already got two minuses. What's wrong?

Comment: That would be practically impossible - most of these errors aren't well defined and may include various conditions to trigger. Besides, all these errors (and other published erratas) are model specific, while emulators are usually ISA specific.

Comment: You asked a vague question with no answer (okay the answer is yes someone has very likely added at least one cpu bug into at least one simulator out there in the world).  You didnt appear to make any effort to find the answer yourself. (Note: I googled the entire internet and found nothing, means you really didnt make an effort because the answer is out there and can be had with google).  This is not a stack overflow question, so it is just a matter of time before it gets closed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such emulators exist, cpu design process require extremely accurate emulators, with precise microarchitecture model. CPU designers need them to debug purposes or to estimate theoretical performance of future chip, also their mangers could calm down investors before chip is ready, by showing some expected functionality. Such emulators is strictly confidential.

Also RTL freeze in CPU design closure born a lot of erratas, or chains of erratas. To simplify future chip bring up, firmware developers could support special tools to emulate functional behavior of expected cpu, with all known erratas implemeted. But them is also proprietary.

But really, it is necessary to understand what is meant by the word "emulator" and "accurate" at that case.
Bochs, as a QEMU, is a functional ISA models, and they purpose is provide some workable architecture profile to run binaries of target ISA, emulation speed is a first goal: there is no micro-architecture modeled: no pipeline, no cache model, no performance monitors, and so on.

To understand kind of BOCHS accuracy, please look to their implementation of CPUID  perfomance monitors and caches topology leafs:
[cpu/cpuid.cc](https://github.com/larsr/bochs/blob/master/cpu/cpuid.cc)

When you specify some cpu at BOCHS, skylake for example, bochs known nothing except CPUID values that belong to that cpu, feature sets in other words: AVX2, FMA, XSAVE etc.

Also BOCHS do not implements precise model/family cpuid values: look for implementation of cpuid version information leaf ([grep](https://github.com/larsr/bochs/blob/master/cpu/cpuid.cc) for get_cpu_version_information function): it is hardcoded value.

So there is no cpu erratas at Bochs.

Comment: Are there any open-source accurate / extremely accurate emulators? And also: if you have RTL, you can run it (with verilator,vcs,etc) precisely (and very slow) with all logically embedded bugs present in it. This is "Cycle-accurate simulator"...

Comment: Extremely accurate emulation need knowledge of micro architecture of specific cpu. It is confidential intellectual property. 
Such tools is unable to be open-source.
Maybe very old processors micro architecture is declassified, and there some fancy people that make such tools. I do not believe in it.

Comment: rtl simulators do not necessarily emulate the silicion nor the bugs.  Like saying I have some C code and no matter what computer I compile it for it runs the same.

Comment: Jettatura, What about open-source CPUs like OpenRISC, recent SuperH [J-Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuperH#J_Core) or many RISC-V cores, including open BOOM out-of-order.

Comment: visual6502 does a gate level simuation, the information was determined by shaving a thin layer off of the device and taking a picture, repeat many times, then figure out from that the connections and the cells.  Some of the undocumented (bugs perhaps the OP might say) features that folks used and relied on were finally after decades understood now that we can reverse engineer the design at least at the gate level, timing based things (you dont want to see what an intel chip used to look like, on die hacking) you cannot do necessarily this is still a functional simulation...

Comment: ...bugs related to race conditions/timing, an HDL simulator or other wont reproduce.

Comment: I forgot about them. They are amazing enthusiasts. Maybe so.  But this conversation was about x86 processors, as i understand, because Bochs is x86 only.

Comment: understood. and the same group may have already started work on early x86 or other chips as well, but current chips, first and foremost there will be chips with different steppings with the same name that have different bugs/features that you may not realize if you buy say a box of 10 of them not knowing it is possible that one or more might be different from the others.  in some cases microcode loading at boot time can fix these (various bios patches that fix various known bugs for a specific chip and stepping)

Comment: as with the 6502 case where undefined opcodes would lead to determinsitic behavior you can try this with "unpredictable results" items from a processors databook and see if they are actually predictable, ARM was well known for doing this, at least a small percentage were in fact predictable and they would use that to see if you stole their IP.  So you could take documented bugs for any chip and if predictable enough you can roll that into an emulator if you want, dont know why you would, but you can.

Comment: emulators like qemu dont even properly emulate the peripherals and likely take shortcuts elsewhere (write bytes into a tx register of a uart as fast as you can on qemu then repeat that on real hardware, see if there is a difference).

Comment: old_timer, i think it is you turn to post answer))